# C++ indentation not working on Vim

Tags: vim

I am having trouble getting indentation to work in Vim. I am coding in C++.
I use vim.nox on ubuntu 9.10
I have filetype plugin indent on
I also tried set cident , set autoindent, set smartindent etc.
Automatic indentation does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to tell where your problem since you do not show your `~/.vimrc`. Do you activate `filetype plugin` at all?

```
set filetype plugin on
```

Comment: Try "filetype plugin indent on"